# MS Access Select Works but Update Won't

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a SQL Server table linked to MS Access as a front end. Select query works but somehow Update does not. I'm using a continuous form and wants to have a "Select All" checkbox which will update all check boxes that they're filtered.

I can manually select checkboxes and they update each row but somehow when I'm using VBA, it doesn't work.

```
SELECT
    dbo_GRC_Assignment.*
FROM
    dbo_GRC_Assignment
WHERE
    isactive = 1
    AND [PM] = 'John Doe'
    AND [Region] IN ('US')
```

The above query works to filter my selection

```
UPDATE
    dbo_GRC_Assignment
SET 
    dbo_GRC_Assignment.[RowSelected] = 1
WHERE
    isactive = 1
    AND [PM] = 'John Doe'
    AND [Region] IN ('US')
```

The above `Update` query does not work at all.

Comment: What is the data-type of the `RowSelected` column? How is it not working? Is there any error message or exception?

Comment: What happens if you have just `SET RowSelected = 0` without including the table name?

Comment: Hi @Dai, no there's no error message.. it's a yes/no field and yes i've tried using SET RowSelected = 0.. It still does not work.. I can use the update query in SQL Server to update my selection but somehow it doesn't work in MS Access

Answer (score 0):

So epic noob fail. I got the execute part commented out. Still legit question.. I only added dbFailOnError and now it works.. It previously didn't..

```
'CurrentDb.Execute strCHKall, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: You might also want to add `dbSeeChanges` to any action query.